# PayPal Preapproved API usage when dealing with user "credits"

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is it possible to use PayPal's preapproved payments api for the following scenario:

Online marketplace where users buy fixed amounts of credits.

They spend the credits on items/services in the marketplace.

We detect when the credits run out and based on the billing agreement automatically charge them to renew the amount of credits.

I have spent quite a while looking around for an answer to this but cannot find my specific problem.

Any help very much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible. I would write a cron job that periodically checks current credits against their billing agreement. If there is a match, then make a pay request to paypal. Sorry I cannot provide code examples without more knowledge of how your site is structured.

Comment: 1) Is it possible to set up using Preapproval API, if not is there a better suited API

2) Can it be setup through PayPal so that the user does not need an existing PayPal account or to create a new one. If there is a way to do this other than preapproval API please let me know as well.

3) We want the billing to be automatic when the user credits run out. Therefore there is no set time, e.g 1 month, when each user is charged. Is this possible?

Comment: It has been a while since I have used Paypal's API, but I know you can do pre-approval with the adaptive payments api. I think they must have an account, or create an account for pre-approval to work. Once you have pre-approval just run a cron to check periodically if they have run out of credits, if they have, bill them for more.